# Non-Hermitian PT-symmetric Interacting Hamiltonian with Real Spectra

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, hamiltonian, eigenvalue, cpt-symmetry

The following hamiltonian is $\mathcal{PT}$-symmetric $$\mathcal{H} = -J \sum_{j = 1}^{2N} [ 1 + (-1)^j \delta ] [ c^{\dagger}_{j} c_{j+1} + h.c. ] + \imath \gamma \sum_{j = 1}^{2N} (-1)^j c^{\dagger}_j c_{j}$$ and it shows real spectra for $\gamma \leq 2J\delta$ (see [PhysRevA.86.042110](https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.86.042110)). But this Hamiltonian is non-interacting. Is there any well-known $\mathcal{PT}$-symmetric interacting model?

Comment: Link to abstract page?

Answer (score 0):

Yes! There are a few Many-body Hamiltonians given in Ref. [PhysRevResearch.2.023286](https://journals.aps.org/prresearch/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevResearch.2.023286) & [PhysRevB.97.201411](https://journals.aps.org/prb/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevB.97.201411).